# how to display specify object value from JSON in laravel table view blade

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, guzzle

i manage to display certain value but not manage for another value in blade table...I want to display value

```
description
```

which is inside

`irel__com_access_level`

from my json response

....here is my response json with code

```
{
            "ID": "cust1",
            "PWD": "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=",
            "NICK_NAME": "CUST1",
            "PWD_INVALID_HIT": "0",
            "PWD_CREATE_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15",
            "INSTITUTION_ID": "C01",
            "ACL_ID": "L04",
            "LOGIN_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15",
            "LOGIN_STS_ID": "N",
            "STS_ID": "C08",
            "TYPE_ID": "U00",
            "UPD_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15",
            "EMAIL_ID": "cust1@gmail.com",
            "PHONE_NO_ID": "0",
            "HP_ID": "0                        ",
            "CRT_DATE_DELETED": null,
            "irel__com_access_level": {
                "ID": "L04",
                "DESCRIPTION": "CUSTOMER",   // i want to display this
                "IS_CREATE": "Y",
                "IS_READ": "Y",
                "IS_UPDATE": "Y",
                "IS_DELETE": "N",
                "STS_ID": "R01",
                "UPD_ID": "shukrimb",
                "UPD_DT": "2018/06/26 11:15:10"
            },

        },
```

in my controller

```
 public function index()
    {

        $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContents());

        return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['content' => $content->data]);

    }
```

my blade file

```
 @foreach($content as $i=>$user)
                        @php
                            $currentRecordno = 1;
                        @endphp
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $currentRecordno + $i }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->ID }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->NICK_NAME }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->PWD_INVALID_HIT }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->???? }}  </td>
```

Comment: If your response is object instance of `User`, as I could see from above, you can access the `irel__com_access_level` properties like this: `$user->irel__com_access_level['DESCRIPTION']`

Comment: just try ur code but got error like "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 1):

in your **Controller** do this:

```
public function index()
    {

        $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContents(), true); //true convert your JSON to array

        return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['content' => $content->data]);

    }
```

then in your **Blade** you can reach this in this way:

```
$user['irel__com_access_level']['DESCRIPTION']
```

Comment: hi sir...error return which is "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: try to `dd()` every level, for example write this in your blade in the `foreach` loop : `@php dd($user); @endphp`,then  if it was your success return then `dd($user['irel__com_access_level'])` , and then if it was your success return do this `dd($user['irel__com_access_level']['DESCRIPTION'])` ---- by this way you can find out where is your problem